Missing locked object in query result
I have following query:
select
 current_timestamp as timestamp,
 ec.session_id,
 er.blocking_session_id,
 es.status,
 er.wait_type,
 er.wait_resource,
 es.last_request_start_time,
 er.wait_time,
 er.last_wait_type,
 owt.resource_description,
 es.transaction_isolation_level,
 es.deadlock_priority,
 es.host_name,
 es.program_name,
 es.client_interface_name,
 er.database_id,
 d.name as database_name,
 o.name as locked_object,
 tl.resource_type,
 est.text
from
 sys.dm_exec_connections ec
 left join sys.dm_exec_requests er on er.session_id = ec.session_id
 left join sys.dm_exec_sessions es on es.session_id = ec.session_id
 left join sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks owt on owt.session_id = ec.session_id
 left join sys.databases d on d.database_id = er.database_id
 left join sys.dm_tran_locks tl on tl.request_session_id = es.session_id and tl.request_status <> 'grant'
 left join sys.partitions p on p.hobt_id = tl.resource_associated_entity_id
 left join sys.objects o on o.object_id = p.object_id
 outer apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(ec.most_recent_sql_handle) est
where
 ec.session_id <> @@spid
 and ec.session_id in
  (select session_id from sys.dm_exec_requests where blocking_session_id <> 0 and database_id = db_id()
  union
  select blocking_session_id from sys.dm_exec_requests where blocking_session_id <> 0 and database_id = db_id())

Most of the time, locked_object returns the resource the session is waiting for but sometimes it does not. Have a look:



timestamp
session_id
blocking_session_id
status
wait_type
wait_resource
last_request_start_time
wait_time
last_wait_type
resource_description
transaction_isolation_level
deadlock_priority
host_name
program_name
client_interface_name
database_id
database_name
locked_object
resource_type
text




2024-12-11 10:06:00.650
78
775
running
LCK_M_IX
OBJECT: 5:658101385:15
2024-12-11 10:05:57.470
3546
LCK_M_IX
objectlock lockPartition=15 objid=658101385 subresource=FULL dbid=5 id=lock1b831a5ce80 mode=S associatedObjectId=658101385
2
5
AppHost
AppWare#1
OLEDB
5
production
NULL
OBJECT
(@kontonr ...


2024-12-11 10:06:00.650
154
187
running
LCK_M_RS_U
KEY: 5:72057619720830976 (ffffffffffff)
2024-12-11 10:05:29.333
31704
LCK_M_RS_U
keylock hobtid=72057619720830976 dbid=5 id=lock1b40b71e400 mode=RangeS-U associatedObjectId=72057619720830976
2
5
WGS03
AppWare#1
OLEDB
5
production
belegemitabgang
KEY
(@P1 int,@...


2024-12-11 10:06:00.650
187
775
running
LCK_M_IX
OBJECT: 5:658101385:3
2024-12-11 10:05:19.903
41123
LCK_M_IX
objectlock lockPartition=3 objid=658101385 subresource=FULL dbid=5 id=lock1bad6750200 mode=S associatedObjectId=658101385
2
5
WGA803
AppWare#1
OLEDB
5
production
NULL
OBJECT
(@kontonr ...


2024-12-11 10:06:00.650
775
0
running
NULL

2024-12-11 10:05:10.460
0
SOS_SCHEDULER_YIELD
NULL
2
5
Jobserver2
AppWare#1
OLEDB
5
production
NULL
NULL
select v.s...



I'm sure I don't understand some things and how they relate to each other.
Why don't session_id 78 and 187 return any locked_object?

The resource_associated_entity_id meaning varies. In those cases it is an actual object id rather than corresponding to a hobt_id - So the object is whatever SELECT OBJECT_NAME(658101385,5) returns
